# SQL Server Insert Data From Excel if Query not exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, excel

My Excel:
[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjYp6.png)

I'm tring to store car toll payments in an Excel file then import them into SQL Server with a Python script. I did it and worked fine but I don't know how to check if some data for example "card number" in Excel does not match with query in table of my database.

My Python script: try to create table first then insert in to table from Excel.

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
#import seaborn as sns
#import scipy.stats as stats
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import pandas.io.sql
import pyodbc
import xlrd

# create Connection and Cursor objects
database = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP-4JP7FB3;"
                      "Database=convert;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = database.cursor()

# read data
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MyExcell/convert/daramad.xls')

# Open the workbook and define the worksheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MyExcell/convert/daramad.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("source")

query1 = """
CREATE TABLE orders (
    Name varchar(255),
    Serial INT,
    Date varchar(255),
    Price INT,
    Card INT
)"""

query = """
INSERT INTO orders (
    Name,
    Serial,
    Date,
    Price,
    Card
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

# execute create table
try:
    cursor.execute(query1)
    database.commit()
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
    pass

# grab existing row count in the database for validation later
cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM orders")
before_import = cursor.fetchone()

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    Name = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    Serial = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    Date = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    Price = sheet.cell(r,3).value
    Card= sheet.cell(r,4).value

    # Assign values from each row
    values = (Name, Serial, Date, Price, Card)

    # Execute sql Query
    cursor.execute(query, values)

# Commit the transaction
database.commit()

# If you want to check if all rows are imported
cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM orders")
result = cursor.fetchone()

print((result[0] - before_import[0]) == len(data.index))  # should be True

# Close the cursor
cursor.close()

# Commit the transaction
database.commit()

# Close the database connection
database.close()
##############################

# Print results
print ("")
print ("All Done! Bye, for now.")
print ("")
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print ("I just imported %s columns and %s rows to SQL-Server!" % (columns, rows))
```

modify my code if possible.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't *ask* anything

Comment: But what is your question? "I want" isn't a question. What is the difficulty you have solving your problem? Why isn't what you have working?

Comment: If you're better at sql than python, i suggest importing all data from excel into some scratch table and then do INSERT/UPDATE into the real table based on whatever logic you are looking for. Actually, i might always suggest that :)

Comment: If you want to do it in your python code then, before execute the insert query in your loop you have to check the `card` value present in database or not.

Comment: @babakgh the technique used in all ETL jobs is to insert the data into a staging table and *then* update/INSERT data into the target using JOINs. That's the fastest and most scalable option.

Answer (score 0):

That's right @PanagiotisKanavos, using a staging table and performing a merge (UPDATE/INSERT) operation based on joins is indeed a more efficient approach in ETL processes. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import xlrd

# create Connection and Cursor objects
database = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                          "Server=DESKTOP-4JP7FB3;"
                          "Database=convert;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = database.cursor()

# read data
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MyExcell/convert/daramad.xls')

# Open the workbook and define the worksheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MyExcell/convert/daramad.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("source")

# Define the CREATE TABLE query for staging table
staging_table_query = """
CREATE TABLE orders_staging (
    Name varchar(255),
    Serial INT,
    Date varchar(255),
    Price INT,
    Card INT
)"""

# Define the INSERT query for staging table
staging_insert_query = """
INSERT INTO orders_staging (
    Name,
    Serial,
    Date,
    Price,
    Card
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

# execute CREATE TABLE query for staging table
try:
    cursor.execute(staging_table_query)
    database.commit()
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
    pass

# Load data into the staging table
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    Name = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
    Serial = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
    Date = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
    Price = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
    Card = sheet.cell(r, 4).value

    # Assign values from each row
    values = (Name, Serial, Date, Price, Card)

    # Execute INSERT query for staging table
    cursor.execute(staging_insert_query, values)

# Commit the transaction for staging table
database.commit()

# Define the MERGE query to update/insert into target table
merge_query = """
MERGE INTO orders AS target
USING orders_staging AS source
ON target.Card = source.Card
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        target.Name = source.Name,
        target.Serial = source.Serial,
        target.Date = source.Date,
        target.Price = source.Price
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Name, Serial, Date, Price, Card)
    VALUES (source.Name, source.Serial, source.Date, source.Price, source.Card);
"""

# Execute the MERGE query
cursor.execute(merge_query)

# Commit the transaction for the target table
database.commit()

# Close the cursor
cursor.close()

# Close the database connection
database.close()

# Print results
print("")
print("All Done! Bye, for now.")
print("")
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print("I just imported %s columns and %s rows to SQL-Server!" % (columns, rows))
```

Comment: That's an extremely slow operation and never used in ETL jobs. Even the `COUNT(*)` is far slower than needed because it has to actually find and count the matching rows.